# Prevent graphql query in vue-apollo if input variable is null

Tags: vuejs2, graphql, vue-apollo

I've been doing some reading and have come up with a query setup for a contact input field.  I would like to avoid running this query at component startup with null input.  I could manually run the queries through computed methods maybe, but is there a simple way to prevent this?

```
apollo: {
    search: { 
        query: () => contactSearchGQL,
        variables() { 
            return { 
                searchText: this.searchText, 
            };
        },
        debounce: 300,
        update(data) { 
            console.log("received data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
            console.log("We got some result!")
        },
        error(error) {
            console.error('We\'ve got an error!', error)
        },
        prefetch() { 
            console.log("contact search, in prefetch");
            if ( this.searchText == null ) return false;
            return true;
        },
    },
},
```

I think I'm not understanding something about prefetch, or if it's even applicable here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should utilize the `skip` option for that, as shown in [the docs](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#skipping-the-query):

```
apollo: {
  search: { 
    query: () => contactSearchGQL,
    variables() { 
      return { 
        searchText: this.searchText, 
      };
    },
    skip() {
      return !this.searchText;
    },
    ...
  },
},
```

Anytime `searchText` updates, `skip` will reevaluate -- if it evaluates to false, the query will be ran. You can also set the skip property directly if you need to control this logic elsewhere in your component:

```
this.$apollo.queries.search.skip = true
```

The `prefetch` option is specific to SSR. By default, `vue-apollo` will prefetch all queries in server-side rendered components. Setting `prefetch` to false disables this functionality for a specific query, which means that particular query won't run until the component is rendered on the client. It does not mean the query is skipped. See [here](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/ssr.html#component-prefetching) for more details about SSR in `vue-apollo`.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo Client

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SOME_DATA_QUERY, {
    variables: { param1 },
    skip: param1 === '',
  })
```

This query will be fired only when param1 is not empty.